# React-Native Passing Parent Function as prop to Child Component

Tags: react-native, components

I'm getting very frustrated because there doesn't seem to be a post that solves my issue. In a Parent Component have an array that stores a list of objects, and a method that appends to this list. [for reference here's a snipbit]

In the render method of my parent component, I pass this method as a prop to my child component.

[line 79]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/fStiF.png

And my child component tries to call said method, in it's render()
[in render's return, child component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/knj8T.png)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/crN9T.png

However for some reason I get an Error this.props.addPart is not a function

Complete Code:

[WaitlistTable.js 1-34](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1CwI8.png)

[WaitlistTable.js render 34-56](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FcMow.png)

[CustomerAdd.js 1-35](https://i.stack.imgur.com/knj8T.png)

[CustomerAdd.js call to addPart in render](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ASmCS.png)

Comment: [**Please do not upload images of text (code/input/output/errors, or otherwise) on Stack Overflow**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). You need to post a [mre] within the question itself, with [correct formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Answer (score 0):

Make your **addPart** function an arrow function

like this

```
addPart = (..,..,..) => {...}
```

Comment: didn't change anything